# Is it possible to describe block comments using EBNF?

Tags: parsing, comments, context-free-grammar, ebnf

Say, I have the following EBNF:

```
document    = content , { content } ;
content     = hello world | answer | space ;
hello world = "hello" , space , "world" ;
answer      = "42" ;
space       = " " ;
```

This lets me parse something like:

```
hello world 42
```

Now I want to extend this grammar with a block comment. How can I do this properly?

If I start simple:

```
document    = content , { content } ;
content     = hello world | answer | space | comment;
hello world = "hello" , space , "world" ;
answer      = "42" ;
space       = " " ;
comment     = "/*" , ?any character? , "*/" ;
```

I cannot parse:

```
Hello /* I'm the taxman! */ World 42
```

If I extend the grammar further with the special case from above, it gets ugly, but parses.

```
document    = content , { content } ;
content     = hello world | answer | space | comment;
hello world = "hello" , { comment } , space , { comment } , "world" ;
answer      = "42" ;
space       = " " ;
comment     = "/*" , ?any character? , "*/" ;
```

But I still cannot parse something like:

```
Hel/*p! I need somebody. Help! Not just anybody... */lo World 42
```

How would I do this with an EBNF grammar? Or is it not even possible at all?

Comment: What tool are you using to test your grammar?

Comment: @whydoubt nothing other than my head.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you would consider "hello" as a token, you would not want anything to break that up.  Should you need to do so, it becomes necessary to explode the rule:

```
hello_world = "h", {comment}, "e", {comment}, "l", {comment}, "l", {comment}, "o" ,
              { comment }, space, { comment },
              "w", {comment}, "o", {comment}, "r", {comment}, "l", {comment}, "d" ;
```

Considering the broader question, it seems commonplace to not describe language comments as part of the formal grammar, but to instead make it a side note.  However, it can generally be done by treating the comment as equivalent to whitespace:

```
space = " " | comment ;
```

You may also want to consider adding a rule to describe consecutive whitespace:

```
spaces = { space }- ;
```

Cleaning up your final grammar, but treating "hello" and "world" as tokens (i.e. not allowing them to be broken apart), could result in something like this:

```
document    = { content }- ;
content     = hello world | answer | space ;
hello world = "hello" , spaces , "world" ;
answer      = "42" ;
spaces      = { space }- ;
space       = " " | comment ;
comment     = "/*" , ?any character? , "*/" ;
```

Comment: In ISO 14977, underscore is an _other character_ (7.5) and should not be used in a _meta-identifier_. See my explanation at [EBNF whitespacing in meta identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53508537/9170346).

Comment: In ISO 14977, repetition may be denoted by using an empty _except_, thus one or more spaces may be shown as _spaces = {" "}-;_. See my explanation at [How to denote at least one repetition in EBNF?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55643354/9170346).

Comment: @RickSmith I had seen underscore used elsewhere and did not realize is should not be used, so I will edit accordingly.  While that notation for one-or-more seems peculiar, and will edit for that as well.

Comment: There are a number of variations under the name EBNF, but the OP used a space in the meta-identifier, which is peculiar to ISO 14977. Have you considered a preprocessor for your answer? It would remove the comments while leaving the remaining text intact. It seems it would provide a cleaner solution.

Comment: @RickSmith Ahhh! I just used the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus–Naur_form) syntax, which seems to be ISO 14977 alright :D

Comment: @whydoubt Thanks for the explanation! I actually thought of your first approach, but found it too annoying to write. The second approach seems to work for me though. Btw. is there any benefit in not allowing comments to split up terminals others than not going to hell for writing a `letter , { comment } , ...` EBNF?

Answer (score 2):

> How would I do this with an EBNF grammar? Or is it not even possible at all?

Some languages remove comments, some replace comments with a space, in a preprocessor. Removing the comments seems the easiest solution to this problem. However, this solution would remove comments from literals, which would not be done, normally.

```
document = preprocess, process;

preprocess = {(? any character ? - comment, ? append char to text ?)},
    ? text for input to process ?;

comment = "/*", {? any character ? - "*/"}, "*/", ? discard ?;

process = {content}-;

content = hello world | answer | spaces;

hello world = ("H" | "h"), "ello", spaces, ("W" | "w") , "orld";

answer = "42";

spaces = {" "}-;
```

The preprocessor, given,

```
Hello /* I'm the taxman! */ World 42
```

produces

```
Hello  World 42
```

Notice the two spaces.

And, for

```
Hel/*p! I need somebody. Help! Not just anybody... */lo World 42
```

produces

```
Hello World 42
```

Comment: Most languages replace comments with a space character (at least, in theory), so `Hel/* ... */lo` is two tokens, not one.

Comment: @rici Ah, theory vs. practice. All(?) languages define comments and where they may be placed. EBNF (6.7) defines comments such that comments may be removed (or replaced by a space) _without affecting the language defined by the syntax_. Other languages with which I am familiar use _end-of-line_ comments and removal or replacement by space is insignificant. However, with LaTex, removal is required since any replacement space would become part of the document.

Comment: EBNF does not allow comments to be placed in the middle of a syntactic element, so you can't token paste around a comment. That's the same as the block comment syntax (`/*...*/`) as used in C, C++, C#, CSS, D, EcmaScript (and variations), Java, PHP, and probably many others, and similar to block comments in, for example, Lua and Haskell. When I said "in theory", I meant that the language processor doesn't need to physically replace the comment with a single whitespace character; it only has to act as though that happened (and it might still count line numbers correctly in error messages).

Comment: @rici In the case of a misplaced comment in EBNF, that would be a syntax error; hence removal or replacement is irrelevant. The questions were: `How would I do this with an EBNF grammar? Or is it not even possible at all?` I provided a how and believe it can be done. It may not be a good way--certainly not the only way--but it is a way (paraphrasing [Nietzsche](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/9213-you-have-your-way-i-have-my-way-as-for)). I have no disagreement with what you've said; it just doesn't seem to apply to this question. Perhaps the OP will ask more about this later.

Comment: Thanks! I'm sorry for not stating this explicitly in the question, but I want to keep my comments in the AST. Thus, while it might work well for other cases, a pre-processor is not what I'm searching for. Still, I give you an upvote for the good answer.